# Add numbers to end of every alternate line before bracket

Tags: linux, string, awk, vim, sed

Need to add consecutive number to a specific location of hosts file in linux

```
awk '0==NR%2{$0} 1' FILE
```

was trying with awk not able to get around

```
[tab-edge]
101.55.12.199
[tab-edge]
101.55.12.193
[tab-edge]
101.55.12.194
[tab-edge]
101.55.12.192
```

expected results

```
[tab-edge1]
101.55.12.199
[tab-edge2]
101.55.12.193
[tab-edge3]
101.55.12.194
[tab-edge4]
101.55.12.192
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/\[tab/{sub(/\]$/,++count"&")} 1' Input_file
```

OR if every line starts from `[` where you want to insert numbers and not with `[tab` then try following.

```
awk '/^\[/{sub(/\]$/,++count"&")} 1'  Input_file
```

---

---

Or with OP's attempt, in case you want to insert count for odd number lines then try following.

```
awk 'FNR%2!=0{sub(/\]$/,++count"&")} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{sub(/]/,(NR+1)/2"&")}1' file
[tab-edge1]
101.55.12.199
[tab-edge2]
101.55.12.193
[tab-edge3]
101.55.12.194
[tab-edge4]
101.55.12.192
```